# div inside div overflows border on specific resolution / zoom level

Tags: html, css

```css
.border {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px #d43f3a solid;
}

.header {
      padding: 10px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
<div class="header">
   non erat euismod convallis vel id libero. Vivamus vel lectus hendrerit, sagittis diam eu, euismod dui. Curabitur quis leo et tellus pharetra tristique ac sit amet lacus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut non turpis risus. Duis vel scelerisque enim. Ut dapibus ut enim ac tempus. Sed sit amet tortor lorem. Vestibulum tincidunt est odio, eu volutpat lacus commodo at. Etiam dapibus nisl ut tempor ultricies. Donec rutrum facilisis purus at al

</div>
<div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tincidunt ultrices venenatis. Nulla sed ex non erat euismod convallis vel id libero. Vivamus vel lectus hendrerit, sagittis diam eu, euismod dui. Curabitur quis leo et tellus pharetra tristique ac sit amet lacus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut non turpis risus. Duis vel scelerisque enim. Ut dapibus ut enim ac tempus. Sed sit amet tortor lorem. Vestibulum tincidunt est odio, eu volutpat lacus commodo at. Etiam dapibus nisl ut tempor ultricies. Donec rutrum facilisis purus at aliquet.
</div>
</div>
```

On first glance it looks perfectly normal, but when you keep zooming in (on my 4k screen at zoom level 150% in chrome) the right border next to the header div becomes different then the other ones.

I made a screenshot how it looks for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WabXv.png

Now, this is fixable if I add `overflow: hidden` to the border class, but then any content that would overflow the div won't show (obviously). For example a custom made select that gets inserted via javascript

Is there a way to fix this? Without `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 1):

let try `margin:0 1px` for `.header` div

Answer (score 0):

This code can fixed your problem but make sure that border width will be 1px fixed, if you want to change border-width you can remove border-width:thin to border:2px solid red; and so on.

```
.border {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px #d43f3a solid;
    border-width: thin;
}
```